# How can I detect a dragged window from another?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

In my application I want to dynamically create windows (NSWindows) and have a special window (which is a NSWindow too and I call dump space) where I can drag the other windows for closing them.

Basically the dump space should detect when I "drop" a window there so it can trigger the action to release and close the window.

Is there something on the Cocoa drag and drop model that I could use? If not I'd like to know some workaround that I could do in order to simulate those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dump space class implement the [NSDraggingDestination](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingDestination_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSDraggingDestination) protocol which has several messages to handle drag operations. In performDragOperation: you can handle your window. I recommend to implement NSDraggingSource in the class that starts dragging a window on `mouseDown:` or `mouseMoved:`. This way you can define your own pasteboard datatype for dragging windows. This can then be used in the dump space to see what was actually dropped on it and trigger your window processing. There's a relatively complicated example for all the required [in this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MultiPhotoFrame/Listings/MultiPhotoFrame_MultiPhotoView_m.html).

Comment: That example goes the opposite direction: dragging an item out of a view creates a window. The questioner is how to asking how to enable dragging the window into the view to consume it and turn it into an item.

Comment: Accepted the answer because I did something similar. I used a `NSString` as my pboardtype, implemented a new UTI so only my application could be destination of my drag actions. Just one extra question if I may: now I need a way to close the window based on the data passed through the pasteboard, I thought in passing an string and store the windows in a global dictionary, so I could close them when dropped on the dump. Is there a smarter way? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think keeping the window in a temporary cache (like the dictionary) is the way to go.